# React POST to Node Server and handle JSON response

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

I am new to React so I am trying to understand how all this works together.

Is there a way to change the component that is rendering for another component after getting a status 200 from a node server?

For Example. I am doing a POST http request from a signup pageto my node with express server. The server response with a json object to my front end. Which Now I want the the profile component/page to render rather than staying at the signup page. This allows me to use the Json data and render it on the profile page. Is this possible? If you have another alternative I am open for suggestions too.

Thanks everyon.

Note:
I am using react router to control the different routes. 
My node server is setup with passport to handle the singup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to manage the state of your application (the user is connected / not connected). Then you can wrap your page inside a component managing the fact that user is connected or not.

Suppose you set user_is_logged as true if the login is successful. You can do something like :

```
var PageWrapper = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        // user_is_logged is true if user is correctly logged
        // LoginPage is the authentication form
        var pageContent = user_is_logged ? this.props.children : <LoginPage />;
        return (
            <div>
                <Menu />
                <div className="container">
                    {pageContent}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    },
});

var MyPage = React.createClass({
    render : function() {
        return (
            <PageWrapper>
                <div>content of page...</div>
            </PageWrapper>
        );
    },
});
```

And re-render the page in the ajax callback :

```
ReactDOM.render (<MyPage />, document.getElementById('my-app'));
```

It works also with React router.

Answer (score 0):

Please, take a look at Redux Architecture available at http://redux.js.org/

Understanding its concepts will make it clear to you the matter.

Then, go to the Advanced Topics of Redux and you will understand how asynchronous requests interact with Redux Components - (http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/

Hope this helps.